# Android tabbed layout activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android programming. I decided that my app will use a tabbed layout with 3 tabs, so I created a main activity and three other tabs are made as fragments (as it is recommended). Works fine. 
The problem is, my app is now controlled from the fragments and I have no idea how to use more activities. Should I create them in fragments, so that I finish with:
main activity: 
 - fragment1: 
 - activity1, activity2 
 - fragment2:
   - activity3 etc

Or what should I do ?

Comment: What kind of you are doing? Based on the app design we can choose activity or fragment approach. If you plan different UI for phone and tablet or if you need to use same component in multiple places of your app, then it is good to with fragment approach.

Comment: Phone app. The idea is to have a few user input fields and store the inputs as text files (one tab)  and be able to read and display them in second tab. The third tab will be some settings.

Comment: As you need tab option, use fragments.

Comment: Ok so should I finish with one activity only ? And do the communication between fragments through this activity ?